# Spring MVC URL with/without extensions

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, spring-mvc

I have a RESTful controller which is configure to a URL say `/dog/walk`. This returns a json.
Now I have done changes such that `/dog/walk.xml` gives me xml out put.
Now the issue is `/dog/walk` has stopped working. its working with `/dog/walk.json` only. I want it to work with both urls.
I am using `ContentNegotiatingViewResolver` in configuration.
Is there a way by which I can make urls work without extensions?

Comment: It'd be useful to have a look at your @RequestMapping annotated methods

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this site may help.

http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-3-mvc-contentnegotiatingviewresolver-example/

Here is a code snippet which might help. This code comes after / outside the ContentNegotiatingViewResolver bean.

```
<!-- If no extension matched, use JSON view -->
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.json.MappingJacksonJsonView">
     <property name="order" value="2" />
</bean>
```